# Weird result of TestDisk

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery, testdisk

I want to recover a HD with an NTFS partition. The use of TestDisk of an image of this HD obtained using `ddrescue` give me this result (after DeepSearch):

```
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk DD2.dd - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121602 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
  MS Data                   264192 1953523711 1953259520 [DD2]
   MS Data                  8169318   12196762    4027445 [~[O^Gi$9L~CM-GM-? ^UM-=]
   MS Data                  8169319   12196763    4027445 [~[O^Gi$9L~CM-GM-? ^UM-=]
   MS Data                254094907  257314044    3219138 [AK^~M~TSM-81 M-$~R*~U|
   MS Data                254094908  257314045    3219138 [AK^~M~TSM-81 M-$~R*~U|
   MS Data                270577222  274604666    4027445 [~[O^Gi$9L~CM-GM-? ^UM-=]
   MS Data                270577223  274604667    4027445 [~[O^Gi$9L~CM-GM-? ^UM-=]
   MS Data                918475211  918481384       6174
   MS Data                918481384  918487557       6174 [Boot]
   MS Data                978544931  978551104       6174
   MS Data                978551104  978557277       6174 [Boot]
   MS Data                987779832  987782711       2880 [EFISECTOR]
   MS Data               1120323411 1120344149      20739 [NO NAME]
   Mac HFS               1169544774 1177933383    8388610 [~?~?~?M-:D^A]
   Mac HFS               1177933380 1186321989    8388610 [~?~?~?M-:D^A]
   MS Data               1373552003 1373558176       6174
   MS Data               1373558176 1373564349       6174 [Boot]
   MS Data               1391240834 1625472641  234231808
Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
                P=Primary  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
NTFS, blocksize=4096, 1000 GB / 931 GiB
```

How can I interpret this weird result? (Normally my HD contains only one NTFS partition)

Comment: Could be old partitions that have never been overwritten.

Comment: Its unlikely a recover will be possible since those results indicate the data wasn't simply deleted it was more likely either replaced or corrupted.

Comment: @Moab I am very surprised. Normally this HDD was new and was provided with a new computer (normally only one NTFS partition...). I obtained this result on a HDD on which CHKDSK deleted the MFT.

Comment: something weird going on, might need the help of a professional data recovery person to sort it out.